# What's making this sound on my Mac? (DeliveryCompleted.aiff)

Tags: audio, notifications

Several times a day, my laptop plays this unknown sound. There's no visual cue that goes along with it and I have no idea what it means.

I assume it wants my attention for something, but without knowing what, I'm stuck. On the other hand, if it's something I don't really need to know, then I want to make it stop.

I managed to track down a file on my system that has the sound...

```
afplay "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/Resources/DeliveryCompleted.aiff"
```

Any ideas as to what that sound is supposed to mean?

Comment: Are you actively using Xcode?

Comment: No, not actively using XCode. The only apps that are actually running in my dock are iTerm2, Chrome, Adium, Mail, and Slack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it was Adium's way of telling me a new contact had signed on. I disabled the sound in Adium's preference and it's gone away.

Answer (score 1):

This sound most likely has nothing to do with Xcode. It is a standard sound used throughout OS X for many purposes, including installer notifications. It is also a ringtone on iOS.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised to find out it's an installer notification. I just turned off sounds from Application Loader in the Notifications settings, so I can see if that stops it.

Comment: Nope, not an installer notification. :(

Answer (score 1):

IIRC [SoundBunny for Mac](https://www.prosofteng.com/soundbunny/) ($10, free 30-day demo available) will show you which apps have recently played sounds on your Mac.